# Passing multiple parameters with serialize jQuery in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have a problem with a serialized form. I need to pass multiple rows for creating an invoice, but it passes just the first row.

This is a form:

```
<form action="" id="generate_invoice" method="POST">
  <td><input type="number" class="form-control n_invoice" name="n_invoice[]"></td>
  <td><input type="date" class="form-control data" name="data[]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control description" name="description[]"></td>
  <td><input type="number" class="form-control price" name="price[]" step=any></td>
  <td><input type="number" class="form-control vat" name="vat[]">
</form>
```

This is a function which adds new rows:

```
function addrow_invoice() {
  var i = $('#invoiceTable tr').length;
  var tr = '<tr>'+
    '<td><input type="checkbox" class="case"/></td>'+
    '<td></td>'+
    '<td></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control description" name="description[]"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" class="form-control price" name="price[]"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" class="form-control vat" name="vat[]"></td>'+
    '</tr>';
  $('table#invoiceTable').append(tr);
  i++;
};
```

And this is a test:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['description']); $i++) 
{
  echo "{$_POST['description'][$i]}";
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your HTML is invalid. The `form` needs to wrap the `table` element, not be inside it. Because the HTML is invalid, the location of the `form` is moved so that it's not wrapping your `input` elements, hence nothing gets serialised.

Your HTML needs to be changed to this:

```html
<form action="" id="generate_invoice" method="POST">
  <table id="invoiceTable">  
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control n_invoice" name="n_invoice[]"></td>
      <td><input type="date" class="form-control data" name="data[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control description" name="description[]"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control price" name="price[]" step=any></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control vat" name="vat[]">
    </tr>
    <!-- additional rows appended here... -->
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: The real problem is when i pass a parameter he is counted but if print doesn't show nothing